# Why won't my Logitech K750 solar keyboard work at the login screen?

Tags: keyboard, logitech

If the keyboard was not touched when on grub, the keyboard will not function at the login screen. Any other person with same problem and how to fix it? Using Ubuntu12.04(3.2.0-26-generic-pae )

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, switching from the USB3.0 port to USB2 port used by the transceiver fixes this problem.

Comment: Not helpful for a mac mini late 2014 model - it has 4 USB 3 ports, no USB 2 ports.